# Some Controls displaces in Grid WPF

Tags: wpf

I test my application on different pcs with different screens, at me the layout looks fine, but when i start my application on a another pc some controls displaces in the grid:

@my Pc where i develope it:
[image]

On other PC:

[image]

code of itemscontrols(which displaces):

```
<ItemsControl Name="itClblMenge" Height="37" ItemsSource="{Binding ArtikelInfo}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="309,37,81,46" Grid.Column="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Height="37" >
                                    <Label  x:Name="lblMenge" >
                                        <Label.Content>
                                            <TextBlock>
                                                <TextBlock.Text>
                                 <MultiBinding StringFormat="}{0} {1}">                                             
                                         <Binding Path="RawQuantity"/>
                                             <Binding Path="QuantityUnit"/>
                                                    </MultiBinding>
                                                </TextBlock.Text>
                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </Label.Content>
                                    </Label>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
```

Has somebody a explanation for this?

Comment: You should show parent panel where `ItemsControl` is placed rather than `ItemsControl` itself since it useless for resolving the issue. By the way you have a lot of redundant elements in `ItemTemplate`: **1)** `Grid` is useless since it contains one element **2)** You don't need `Label`, use `TextBlock` only.

Comment: i got the itemscontrols in a grid, oh thanks for the objection.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar problems before. Running Windows 7 WPF apps on old XP machines. I imagine building NET 4.7 app might have wobbles on a Windows 7 machine.

1. Check the NET Framework installed on both machines, and what your building against
2. What version of Windows are each running?
3. How are installing the application on the other machine? If you find differences in the machines, perhaps consider using ClickOnce to try and satisfy software requirements - if it's too labour intensive to update the other computer.

Comment: i use .net 4.0, the tested on a another machine also with same .net and same windows just another screen, it displaces ....

Comment: @JulPod why are you using such an old version of .NET?